# How to use a custom generic type as a key in a Dictionary?

Tags: c#

I want to use a custom generic class as a key in a dictionary. How should I override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`?

Eg,

```
public class SomeKey<T,V>
{
    public T Value1 { get; set; }
    public V Value2 { get; set; }

    public SomeKey(T val1, V val2)
    {
        this.Value1 = val1;
        this.Value2 = val2;
    }

    public override bool Equals(SomeKey<T,V> otherKey)
    {
        //whats the best option here?
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        //whats the best option here?
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Equality is simple: test for `Value1` and `Value2` being equal.

For the hash code the simplest approach is to use xor to combine the hash codes from `Value1` and `Value2`.

```
public override bool Equals(SomeKey<T,V> otherKey)
{
    return Value1.Equals(otherKey.Value1) && Value2.Equals(otherKey.Value2);
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return Value1.GetHashCode() ^ Value2.GetHashCode();
}
```

There are lots of alternative ways of calculating the hash code.  If performance is a bottleneck then you should consider something more tailored than xor.

For example, Stack Overflow offers these links (and many more):

- [Custom type GetHashCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059994/custom-type-gethashcode)
- [What is the best algorithm for an overridden System.Object.GetHashCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode)

Comment: sounds good. care to elaborate or give a link on why xor is a good idea?

Comment: Well, for the hash code the best choice depends very much on the distribution of values. xor is a pretty reliable, simple, approach that you can use if you know nothing about the distribution of values.  If OP knows such information, then other choices may be appropriate. All this only matters if the hash code is a performance bottleneck.

Comment: But if he creates two SomeKey<T,V> with the same values, should them be threated the same?

Comment: @Marino they are treated the same.

Comment: another comment on you latest addition, equality comparison == wont work on generic type definitions if there is no where constraint that says this is possible

Comment: @Marino I think I've fixed that now with `Equals()`.  Is that right?

Comment: Any particular reason you’re using `&` and not `&&`?

Answer (score 1):

You should override it in a way that `GetHashcode` reliably returns the same value for the same object, and `Equals` to always return true for the same objects. The [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) has some advices for implementing `GetHashcode` (the remarks section).