# WPF - Restore Previous SelectedItem when ComboBox ItemSource Changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I'm implementing a ComboBox that can be refreshed by users using a button. I'm trying to make it so that the previously selected item is automatically reselected if still present inside the ComboBox after a refresh.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<ComboBox Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" DisplayMemberPath="Name" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Enabled}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=SelectedItem}" Width="379"/>
<Button Content="{x:Static p:Resources.TextRefresh}" Canvas.Right="10" Canvas.Top="10" Click="OnClickButtonRefresh" Width="75"/>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = m_BrowserInstances = new BrowserInstancesViewModel();
}

private void OnClickButtonRefresh(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    m_BrowserInstances.Populate();
}
```

**[EDITED TO CURRENT VERSION]** BrowserInstancesViewModel.cs:

```
public sealed class BrowserInstancesViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private Boolean m_Enabled;
    public Boolean Enabled
    {
        get { return m_Enabled; }
    }

    private BrowserInstance m_SelectedItem;
    public BrowserInstance SelectedItem
    {
        get { return m_SelectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (m_SelectedItem != value)
            {
                m_SelectedItem = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<BrowserInstance> m_Items;
    public ObservableCollection<BrowserInstance> Items
    {
        get { return m_Items; }
    }

    public BrowserInstancesViewModel()
    {
        Populate();
    }

    private static Func<BrowserInstance, Boolean> Recover(BrowserInstance selectedItem)
    {
        return x =>
        {
            Process currentProcess = x.Process;
            Process selectedProcess = selectedItem.Process;

            if (currentProcess.Id != selectedProcess.Id)
                return false;

            if (currentProcess.MainModule.BaseAddress != selectedProcess.MainModule.BaseAddress)
                return false;

            if (currentProcess.MainWindowTitle != selectedProcess.MainWindowTitle)
                return false;

            return true;
        };
    }

    public void Populate()
    {
        BrowserInstance item = m_SelectedItem;
        List<BrowserInstance> items = new List<BrowserInstance>();

        foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome"))
            items.Add(new BrowserInstance(process));

        if (items.Count > 0)
        {
            m_Enabled = true;

            m_Items = new ObservableCollection<BrowserInstance>(items.OrderBy(x => x.Process.Id));

            if (item != null)
                m_SelectedItem = m_Items.SingleOrDefault(Recover(item));

            if (m_SelectedItem == null)
                m_SelectedItem = m_Items[0];
        }
        else
        {
            m_Enabled = false;

            m_Items = new ObservableCollection<BrowserInstance>();
            m_Items.Add(new BrowserInstance());

            m_SelectedItem = m_Items[0];
        }

        NotifyPropertyChanged("Enabled");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Items");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
    }
}
```

I can get back the previously selected item, but only sometimes. Looks like the code is not working properly when I need to select a default value (Index 0) if the previous selected item cannot be recovered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `m_SelectedItem` to the item found by `SingleOrDefault(Recover(...))`.

Currently, you are setting it to the old instance. That instance no longer exists in the list and apparently your `BrowserInstance` class doesn't implement any equality members.

Correct code based on your current code:

```
if(selectedItem != null)
    m_SelectedItem = m_Items.SingleOrDefault(Recover(selectedItem));
if(m_SelectedItem == null)
    m_SelectedItem = m_Items[0];
```

Update:

The code you uploaded has two problems.

1. The value of the `Process` property of the default `BrowserInstance` object that you add if there is no process is `null`. This leads to a `NullReferenceException` in the comparison code used by `SingleOrDefault`.
   Fix it by changing the preceding `if` to

   ```
   if(selectedItem != null && selectedItem.Process != null)
   ```
2. At the end of the `Populate` method you raise the `PropertyChanged` event for `Items` - to update the values in the combobox - and for `SelectedItem` - to set the selected item to the one the user had previously selected.
   The problem here is that WPF will update `SelectedItem` with `null` when `PropertyChanged` is raised for `Items` as it doesn't find the previously selected item in the new item list. This effectively overwrites the new selected item you computed in the `Populate` method.
   Fix it by not assigning the new selected item to `m_SelectedItem` but to `selectedItem` and assign that value to `SelectedItem` after the  `PropertyChanged` event for `Items` was raised:

   ```
   public void Populate()
   {
       BrowserInstance selectedItem = m_SelectedItem;
       List<BrowserInstance> items = new List<BrowserInstance>();

       foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome"))
           items.Add(new BrowserInstance(process));

       if (items.Count > 0)
       {
           m_Enabled = true;

           m_Items = new ObservableCollection<BrowserInstance>(items.OrderBy(x => x.Process.Id));

           if (selectedItem != null && selectedItem.Process != null)
               selectedItem = m_Items.SingleOrDefault(x => (x.Process.Id == selectedItem.Process.Id) && (x.Process.MainModule.BaseAddress == selectedItem.Process.MainModule.BaseAddress));

           if (selectedItem == null)
               selectedItem = m_Items[0];
       }
       else
       {
           m_Enabled = false;

           m_Items = new ObservableCollection<BrowserInstance>();
           m_Items.Add(new BrowserInstance());

           selectedItem = m_Items[0];
       }

       NotifyPropertyChanged("Enabled");
       NotifyPropertyChanged("Items");
       SelectedItem = selectedItem;
   }
   ```

---

If you would properly implement equality for `BrowserInstance` you could make use of the WPF feature that keeps the currently selected item.
The code of `Populate` can be simplified like this:

```
public void Populate()
{
    BrowserInstance selectedItem = m_SelectedItem;
    List<BrowserInstance> items = new List<BrowserInstance>();

    foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome"))
        items.Add(new BrowserInstance(process));

    m_Enabled = items.Any();
    m_Items = new ObservableCollection<BrowserInstance>(items.OrderBy(x => x.Process.Id));
    if(!m_Enabled)
        m_Items.Add(new BrowserInstance());

    NotifyPropertyChanged("Enabled");
    NotifyPropertyChanged("Items");
    if (SelectedItem == null)
        SelectedItem = m_Items[0];
}
```

The equality implementation of `BrowserInstance` looks like this:

```
public sealed class BrowserInstance : IEquatable<BrowserInstance>
{

    // ...

    public bool Equals(BrowserInstance other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;
        if (m_Process == null)
        {
            if (other.m_Process == null)
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        if (other.m_Process == null)
            return false;

        return m_Process.Id == other.m_Process.Id && m_Process.MainModule.BaseAddress == other.m_Process.MainModule.BaseAddress;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as BrowserInstance);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return m_Process != null ? ((m_Process.Id.GetHashCode() * 397) ^ m_Process.MainModule.BaseAddress.GetHashCode()) : 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks! What is the best way to implement equality members on a custom class? My BrowserInstance class has only two fields: `System.Diagnostics.Process` Process and `System.String Name`... all I would have to to is compare the processes, but I can't find a way to properly check if two processes are identical.

Comment: @Zarathos: You would need to override `Object.Equals` and `Object.GetHashCode`. How exactly you perform the comparison is up to you and your program. It depends on how you define equality for a BrowserInstance. For example, you could use the logic from `Recover`.

Comment: Mhhhh... I'm testing my code and I still see some problems. If I keep on pushing the Refresh button, for an unknown reason, the ComboBox selected item is blinking (sometimes it's empty, sometimes not). I can't understand the reason. I edited the question with my edited code following your suggestions.

Comment: @Zarathos: You didn't edit it the way I showed. Please note the difference between `selectedItem` and `m_SelectedItem` in my code. `selectedItem` has been taken from the previous version of your code and contains the item that has been selected before the user clicked "Refresh".

Comment: Ahem sorry. Ok I modified it correctly now. But there is still something wrong that happens when I have a selected item and I click on the Refresh button very quickly. It should always keep the current one... but in fact sometimes SelectedItem is null and no value is selected from the ComboBox. It looks like after SingleOrDefault something bad happens and I can't select the first item in list or the selected item that I get from it is wrong.

Comment: Please add `if(m_SelectedItem == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("SelectedItem should never be null");` right before the calls to `NotifyPropertyChanged` in `Populate`. Please check if that exceptions gets thrown or not.

Comment: @Zarathos: If you can upload a small sample that demonstrates this behavior I can more easily find the cause.

Comment: Euh... can you just explain me why you used `m_Process.Id.GetHashCode() * 397` in `BrowserInstance.GetHashCode()`?

Comment: @Zarathos: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102742/why-is-397-used-for-resharper-gethashcode-override

Comment: Hi Daniel! Thank you very much again for your help. Testing my code, I found something really weird and hard to debug. Just try this: open Google Chrome with 3 tabs (each one pointing to a different website) and, from the ComboBox, select the only entry which have a window title... then hit Refresh: nothing happens as expected. Now, in Chrome, activate / bring to front another tab, hit Refresh and open the ComboBox dropdown: you will notice that the selected entry in the list has a different title. WTF?! Do you have any idea? http://www.filedropper.com/hackse

Comment: @Zarathos: The reason is simple: You only compare the process ID and the base address but you don't compare the name. You need to add that, too.