# Dictionary.ContainsKey Always Returns False

Tags: c#, dictionary

Well i am trying to create a small application that saves some employees Names, Ages as well as salaries. So i decided to use `Dictionary` in order to set every employee's salary and i came up with that code

## Code

```
var employeeSalaryDictionary = new Dictionary<Employee, int>();
employeeSalaryDictionary.Add(new Employee { Name = "Chuck", Age = 37 }, 1000);
employeeSalaryDictionary.Add(new Employee { Name = "Norris", Age = 37 }, 2000);
employeeSalaryDictionary.Add(new Employee { Name = "Rocks", Age = 44 }, 3000);

Employee employeeToFind = new Employee { Name = "Chuck", Age = 37 };
//or even
Employee employeeToFind = new Employee { Name = "Chuck"};

//Always False...
bool exists = employeeSalaryDictionary.ContainsKey(employeeToFind);
```

## Employee Class

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

**However** as i commented out or as the topic title states, `.ContainsKey` always returns me `False` although i tried both ways as shown in the code.

Comment: You should override Equals and GetHashCode for your Employee class

Comment: I think it has something to do with the way objects are compared. Since objects in the dictionary and in `employeeToFind` are in fact different objects - comparing them returns false

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're not using the `Dictionary` constructor that takes in the `IEqualityComparer<T>` and neither have you implemented custom equality on the `Employee` class.

So right now the dictionary is comparing employees by reference. When you `new` an employee, you have a *different* reference, even though e.g. name might be the same.

Probably the easiest way here would be to implement your own `IEqualityComparer<Employee>`, where you could pick which members will be used for equality comparison, and pass it to the dictionary's constructor.

[EDIT] As promised, snippets:

```
//ReSharper's courtesy
public sealed class NameAgeEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Employee>
{
    public bool Equals(Employee x, Employee y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        if (x.GetType() != y.GetType()) return false;
        return string.Equals(x.Name, y.Name) && x.Age == y.Age;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Employee obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return ((obj.Name != null ? obj.Name.GetHashCode() : 0) * 397) ^ obj.Age;
        }
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var employeeSalaryDictionary = new Dictionary<Employee, int>(new NameAgeEqualityComparer());
employeeSalaryDictionary.Add(new Employee { Name = "Chuck", Age = 37 }, 1000);
employeeSalaryDictionary.Add(new Employee { Name = "Norris", Age = 37 }, 2000);
employeeSalaryDictionary.Add(new Employee { Name = "Rocks", Age = 44 }, 3000);

Employee employeeToFind = new Employee { Name = "Chuck", Age = 37 };
bool exists = employeeSalaryDictionary.ContainsKey(employeeToFind); // true!
```

For completeness, here's name-only comparer (also ReSharper's courtesy):

```
 public sealed class NameEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Employee>
 {
        public bool Equals(Employee x, Employee y)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
            if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
            if (x.GetType() != y.GetType()) return false;
            return string.Equals(x.Name, y.Name);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Employee obj)
        {
            return (obj.Name != null ? obj.Name.GetHashCode() : 0);
        }
  }
```

But, as you noticed, you have to decide which comparer you will use for key-comparison when you create a dictionary. That can't be changed later on...

Comment: That is nice but can you make your answer more rich by adding code snippets of how could i or any one else who will see that question solve this problem according to the codes i have posted ?

Comment: @RuneS Sure, give me a sec to spool up Visual Studio ;)

Comment: Could you explain why you added the  `* 397`?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici That's generated by ReSharper, potential reasons are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/102878/1180426). Other good hash-code implementation, that's also easier to remember than this one, is the one from 'Effective Java' - I've seen Jon Skeet using it here and there...

Comment: @PatrykCwiek : That is truly epic! thank you very much for your very nice, detailed help...

Answer (score 4):

Employee is a reference type. Your dictionary key when you add a new employee is going to contain the reference address to that Employee object. If you create another Employee object it has a difference reference than your first Employee object, even though they contain the same data