# C# SetEquals on HashSet<List<float>> is false when expected true

Tags: c#, .net, generics, set, hashset

A Python developer doing some C# (.NET 4.6, Visual Studio 2015 Professional) work here. I am trying to check whether two `HashSet`s are equal.

I have two `HashSet<List<float>>` which I am trying to compare using

`thisList.SetEquals(otherList);`

However, this returns `false` on my data. Using the sample from the [MSDN `HashSet`'s examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355623(v=vs.110).aspx) does work as expected. However, in the samples they use `HashSet<int>` whereas I use `HashSet<List<float>>`.

As I could not found a way to print the `HashSet` contents into Immediate Window in Visual Studio (`ToString` returns `"System.Collections.Generic.HashSet1[System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Single]]"`), I use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(thisList);` to dump the data into a `.json` file on disk.

Two files (each for each `HashSet` contents is:

`[[10.0,15.0],[20.0,25.0]]` and `[[10.0,15.0],[20.0,25.0]]`

Inspecting the `HashSet`s in Visual Studio while debugging looks like this:

```
-       thisList    Count = 2   System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<System.Collections.Generic.List<float>>
-       [0] Count = 2   System.Collections.Generic.List<float>
        [0] 10  float
        [1] 15  float
+       Raw View        
-       [1] Count = 2   System.Collections.Generic.List<float>
        [0] 20  float
        [1] 25  float
+       Raw View        
+       Raw View        
-       otherList   Count = 2   System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<System.Collections.Generic.List<float>>
-       [0] Count = 2   System.Collections.Generic.List<float>
        [0] 20  float
        [1] 25  float
+       Raw View        
-       [1] Count = 2   System.Collections.Generic.List<float>
        [0] 10  float
        [1] 15  float
+       Raw View        
+       Raw View
```

Each `HashSet` contains two lists (order is not of relevance, since it is a set) and each list has identical values (with the same order). They should be considered equal.

What should I do to make these `HashSet`s to be considered equal with `thisList.SetEquals(otherList);`?

**EDIT:**

Printing `coord.ToString("G17")` on each float:

```
10
15
20
25
20
25
10
15
```

Comment: In short, because list equality is going to be based on ReferenceEquals and most likely you have two different list objects in each collection (even if perhaps with the same values). And that's before getting into the problem of comparing floats with strict equality. But what are you trying to accomplish with a HashSet of lists? This feels like a bit of an X-Y problem

Comment: I love the smell of X/Y on a friday afternoon

Comment: @lc, thanks for the comment. I have a toy `PointCollection` class with `X` and `Y` properties for the points. I am implementing an `Equals` method to check whether two collections are equal and this would be when each of the class instances have the same number of points each of which having the same `X` and `Y` coordinates. Should I be using the tuples instead of the lists in a HashSet? Because in Python, `set([(10.0, 15.0), (20.0, 25.0)]) == set([(20.0, 25.0), (10.0, 15.0)])` is `True`.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, updated the question body.

Comment: It's literally an XY problem :)

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov, because you have a List<float> instead of a Vec2 class with appropriate equality members, you are doing a reference comparison. Make a Vec2 class/struct and override the equality members.

Comment: @MineR: From where do you have it that `.SetEquals` does reference comparison?

Comment: Because what's in the HashSet is a List<T> and the equality members for a List<T> are the same as object.

Comment: Ah, I missed the list level, sorry, never mind any of my comments. I thought I saw `HashSet<float>`.

Comment: @MineR, ah, so you suggest I compare two `HashSet<Point>` where each `Point` would be considered equal to another `Point` where their XY would be identical (I will override `Equals` method in the `Point` class)? Did I get it right?

Comment: Yes - you need to override Equals and GetHashCode... in your point class.

Comment: You should provide the `IEqualityComparer<T>` type object while initializing `HashSet`. See the posted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using List in your HashSet, it is comparing the two lists as references instead of considering the values in the Lists.

Instead of using a List to represent an X and Y, use a Vector2 or Point class. This is more or less what the struct should look like:

```
public struct Point
{
    public double X {get; }
    public double Y { get; }

    public Point(double x, double y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public bool Equals(Point other)
    {
        return X.Equals(other.X) && Y.Equals(other.Y);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        return obj is Point && Equals((Point) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return (X.GetHashCode() * 397) ^ Y.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I already had the `Point` class with `Equals (Point other)` overloaded, however, I needed to add `Equals(object obj)` and `GetHashCode`. It's all working now as expected. Mind writing a couple of words on why do you need `Equals(object obj)`and what is the 397 (I guess a random seed value for hashing?)

Comment: You don't actually need the Equals(Point other) - it is just somewhat nicer/faster when you are comparing two points because it doesn't have to do the if statement/casting. With GetHashCode, the point is to come up with as unique a number as possible while still ensuring that anything that can possibly be equal will have the same number. That code is auto generated by Resharper (coding tool) - I assume they have some reason for 397, which is probably explained somewhere on SO.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102742/why-is-397-used-for-resharper-gethashcode-override

Comment: FWIW you might not need to reinvent the wheel if you can use [`System.Drawing.PointF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pointf(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @lc. I thought that too intially, but PointF doesn't override GetHashCode and is not immutable

Comment: @MineR Eww, [you're totally right](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Advanced/PointF.cs,b4963c55b18ead87). I didn't realize that - seems like a rather "interesting" design decision.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to check equal operation of `HashSet<List<float>>` with another object of `HashSet<List<float>>`. The question here is that why it is returning **false**?

Now, before we talk about `HashSet<List<float>>`, let's talk about if I check equal (using below code) for `List<float>` with another object of `List<float>`, then what would be the output?

```
    List<float> list = new List<float>() { 10.0f, 15.0f};
    List<float> anotherList = new List<float>() { 10.0f, 15.0f};

    Console.WriteLine(list.Equals(anotherList));
```

The output of this will be

> false

Since here `Equals` compare the references of the objects (which aren't equal).

**Now to solution to your problem**

You should provide a `EqualityComparer` while initializing the HashSet which should check the type T as needed.

```
    HashSet<List<float>> HashSet1 = new HashSet<List<float>>(new FloatListComparer());
    anotherHashSet1.Add(list);

    HashSet<List<float>> anotherHashSet2 = new HashSet<List<float>>();
    anotherHashSet2.Add(anotherList);

    Console.WriteLine(anotherHashSet1.SetEquals(anotherHashSet2));
```

The output of above code is

> true

The `EqualityComparer` I've written here is looks like as follows.

```
public class FloatListComparer : EqualityComparer<List<float>>
{
    public override bool Equals(List<float> list1, List<float> list2)
    {
        return list1.SequenceEqual(list2);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(List<float> s)
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now question here is that why `SetEquals` is not working

If you check the implementation of `SetEquals` at [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,5650dd9d9a68789b), then you will find that it calls the default comparer of T which works based on checking the reference of objects. By providing the Comparer, `SetEquals` uses the specified one.

Check the live fiddler [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rjKfL9).

Comment: This is a good alternative, but you shouldn't sort the lists as what's in the lists are X,Y coordinates...

Comment: @MineR - SO has asked the question for `HashSet<List<float>>` so I've provided the implementation based on that. See the line in his question --- `I have two HashSet<List<float>> which I am trying to compare using`. Also, there are many ways to Compare two lists, I've provided one of the approach.

Comment: This solution treats the lists as lists, which is not really what was asked for, taking the entire question in consideration. He wants to treat the data as sets all the way down. Semantically,  SetEquals should treat [1,1,1] == [1]

Comment: yes, the SetEquals method ignores duplicate entries and treat [1,1,1] == [1].