# Can we compare two complex collections field by field using IEqualityComparer interface using LINQ extension method SequenceEqual

Tags: c#, linq, iequalitycomparer

I'm trying to use `IEqualityComparer` to compare 2 fields from 2 collections field by field. `IEqualityComparer` is comparing only 1 field "name". I want to compare "mark" as well.

In Java, we have `comparator` interface to compare more than one fields in `Equals` method.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            IList<Student> studentList1 = new List<Student>()
            {
                new Student(){ name="aaaaa", mark = 95, },
                new Student(){ name="bbbb", mark = 25, },
                new Student(){ name="ccc",  mark = 80 }
            };

            IList<Student> studentList2 = new List<Student>()
            {
                new Student(){ name="aaaaa", mark = 95, },
                new Student(){ name="bbbb", mark = 5, },
                new Student(){ name="ccc",  mark = 80 }
            };

            bool isEqual = studentList1.SequenceEqual(studentList2, new StudentComparer());
            Console.WriteLine("Names in 2 collections are {0}", isEqual?"equal":"not equal");   
        }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int mark { get; set; }
    }

    public class StudentComparer : IEqualityComparer<Student>
    {
        public bool Equals(Student x, Student y)
        {
            if (x.name == y.name)
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Student obj)
        {
            return obj.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Actual Result:
Names in 2 collections are equal
Expected Result:
Names in 2 collections are equal
Marks in 2 collections are not equal

Comment: Use reflection and compare each property of these two objects to know that each value of the property is equal or not..

Comment: Why not just add a comparison for marks aswell in the equals method? And how can you expect 2 outputs from one console writeline?

Comment: Console.WriteLine("Marks in 2 collections are {0}", isEqual?"equal":"not equal"); I will add this line. Also I will add comparison for marks also. But I'm not sure how to write the mark comparison in Equals method. How the linq query will differentiate the difference between name and mark comparison.

Comment: if (x.name == y.name && x.mark == y.mark) return true; //This way also I can achieve comparison of 2 fields. Is there any other way differentiate the linq query. bool isNameEqual = studentList1.SequenceEqual(studentList2, new StudentComparer()); //using this I will print Name is equal. bool isMarkEqual = studentList1.SequenceEqual(studentList2, new StudentComparer()); //using this I will print marks are not equal.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue here is that `Object.GetHashCode()` is necessarily unique between objects. This means that when `SequenceEqual(…)` calls `comparer.GetHashCode(…)`, it will get different values for different instances of objects, despite the fact that you have declared them equal in `StudentComparer.Equals(…)`.

What all of this means is that, you should return hash codes which are unique in only the situations where instances of Student are unique according to the IEqualityComparer. For example, you could change your implementation of `StudentComparer.GetHashCode(Student obj)` to:
`return obj.name.GetHashCode()`

Answer (score 1):

Need to correctly implement the equality comparer like this (this code has been generated by [R#](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Generation__Generating_Equality_Comparer.html)):

```
public sealed class StudentComparer  : IEqualityComparer<Student>
{
    public bool Equals(Student x, Student y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
        if (x.GetType() != y.GetType()) return false;
        return string.Equals(x.name, y.name) && x.mark == y.mark;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Student obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return ((obj.name != null ? obj.name.GetHashCode() : 0) * 397) ^ obj.mark;
        }
    }
}
```

PS [Why is '397' used for ReSharper GetHashCode override?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102742/why-is-397-used-for-resharper-gethashcode-override).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to check whether are the names and marks equal in the `Equals` method and get the hash-code of the `name` property individually as well as `mark` property for `IEqualityComparer` to work correctly.

Modify your code to this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IList<Student> studentList1 = new List<Student>()
        {
            new Student { name = "aaaaa", mark = 95, },
            new Student { name = "bbbb", mark = 25, },
            new Student { name = "ccc",  mark = 80 }
        };

        IList<Student> studentList2 = new List<Student>()
        {
            new Student { name = "aaaaa", mark = 95, },
            new Student { name = "bbbb", mark = 5, },
            new Student { name = "ccc",  mark = 80 }
        };

        bool isEqual = studentList1.SequenceEqual(studentList2, new StudentComparer());
        Console.WriteLine("Contents in 2 collections are {0}", isEqual ? "equal" : "not equal");
    }
}

public class Student
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int mark { get; set; }
}

public class StudentComparer : IEqualityComparer<Student>
{
    public bool Equals(Student x, Student y)
    {
        //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data. 
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;

        //Check whether any of the compared objects is null. 
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        return string.Equals(x.name, y.name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && x.mark == y.mark;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Student student)
    {
        //Check whether the object is null 
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(student, null))
            return 0;

        //Get hash code for the name field if it is not null
        int nameHashCode = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(student.name) ? 0 : student.name.GetHashCode();

        // Get hash code for marks also if its not 0
        int marksHashCode = student.mark == 0 ? 0 : student.mark.GetHashCode();

        return nameHashCode ^ marksHashCode;
    }
}
```

Outputting:

```
 Contents in 2 collections are not equal
```

Comment: if (x.name == y.name && x.mark == y.mark)
return true; //This way also I can achieve comparison of 2 fields.
Is there any other way differentiate the linq query.
bool isNameEqual = studentList1.SequenceEqual(studentList2, new StudentComparer()); //using this I will print Name is equal.
bool isMarkEqual = studentList1.SequenceEqual(studentList2, new StudentComparer()); //using this I will print marks are not equal.

Comment: @HEMAMBUJAVALLYVIRAPPANE basically you cant use `SequenceEqual` to check for individual properties as you're expecting

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you add the IEquatable Interface to your Student class, as it is less code and more clearly what you want to achive:

```
public class Student : IEquatable<Student>
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int mark { get; set; }

public bool Equals(Student other)
    {
        if (string.Equals(name, other.name) && mark == other.mark)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

You can leave out the additional StudentComparer implementation.